# Quasar 2 vue js mask issue with thousand operator with optional decimal places

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, masking

I am trying to use thousand operator with optional decimal places allow but not working with quasar default mask

please check below is my code i am using

```
<q-input
          v-model="column"
          mask="#,###,###,###,###"
          prefix="$"
          persistent
          reverse-fill-mask
          unmasked-value             
        />
```

above masking is working good with thousand operator but now i want to allow optional decimal place too

i tried

`mask="#,###,###,###,###.##"` but it puts by default .00 always at end of the value i want to keep it optional for example if user entered decimal then only decimal show otherwise it should not show.

for example expected result

```
1,234
1,234.12
456
7,888
8,896.33
```

Comment: You might have to build this functionality yourself, BUT I think there's potentially a good way to do it. You have the `mask` as a variable, which is by default just '#,###,###,###,###', and you listen to the input for a `.` keypress - when you see it, change the mask variable to '#,###,###,###,###.##'. I don't know the full details of how that would work, or if that would work, so you'll have to experiment.

Comment: @TKoL ok but for example from database by default both types of values are coming then how we can apply it commonly ?